# Can't Resize Both Static and Draggable elements at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i have following fiddle
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wnqj0uta/52/)

[**Resizing of White divs**](http://jsfiddle.net/wnqj0uta/55/)

I have the draggable divs(red) and static divs (white & in the droppable fields )

My purpose is to make them both resize, but i can't

Can any one help

In the document ready function  i comment the code that is responsble for re-sizing the

both red(draggable) and static(white) fields . the problem is they are not working at same time , any help regards this

**Jquery Code**

```
$(function () { 

    // responsible for resizing the draggable elements (red)
    $('.resize_box').resizable({ handles:  'e' });

    // responsible for resizing the static elements (white)
    $('.resize_box').resizable({
                handles: { 'e': '.ui-resizable-e' }
            });

    $(".selectorField").draggable({
                helper: "clone",
                stack: "div",
                cursor: "pointer",
                cancel: null
            });

            function makeDraggable($sel) {
                $sel.find('.resize_box').resizable({
                    handles: { 'e': '.ui-resizable-e' }
                });
            }

            $(".droppedFields").droppable({
                accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var draggable = ui.draggable;
                    draggable = draggable.clone();
                    draggable.addClass('hers');

                    makeDraggable(draggable); //NEW
                    draggable.appendTo(this);
                    $(ui.draggable).hide();
                    alert("drop");


                    $(".droppedFields").sortable({
                        cancel: null, 
                        connectWith: ".droppedFields"
                    }).disableSelection();

                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: Hmm, it appears as if the draggable function is fired before the resize function with the white boxes.  What does the final DIV look like that you are trying to both drag and resize?  Can you add a draggable handle (see API) to the top?

Comment: White boxes are static, there is no concern of them with the drop function,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wnqj0uta/55/ see this i comment out the line 4 and now white boxes are resizble but red are not resized @Michael

Comment: First, you have 4 id="new" in your code...each ID needs to be unique (and it greatly helps with debugging).  Secondly, simply add a different resize class for the red and the white.  http://jsfiddle.net/wnqj0uta/56/

Comment: actually the divs are added dynamically so i cant change the id new  to differnt evry time, secondly let i am adding draggable.addClass('hers'); to the red feilds, but i cant find there click or make them resize with class name different from the white

Comment: have you got it  what i said @Michael

Comment: I understand about not being able to change the ID's because it is dynamic (although this could potentially be a big problem; either remove the ID's or make them unique).  I don't understand the second part (and the post-rendered markup of the jQuery HTML makes it super difficult to read).  If commenting out line 4 makes the White DIVs behave how you want, simply come up with a selector that excludes the white DIVs (I did this with a new class name, but you can do it differently) and call the .resizable method again.

Comment: can you please upvote my answer so that i come for discussion room

Comment: please help m realy stucked man @Michael

Comment: What exactly is working and what exactly is not working?  Is http://jsfiddle.net/wnqj0uta/55/ working exactly how you want it except for the red boxes?

Comment: If my comment above is correct, then try http://jsfiddle.net/wnqj0uta/58/.

Comment: Aright, I will move this down as an answer and you can upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the proper selectors for the jQuery UI resizable functions.  Based off your jsFiddle, you should make sure that the line of the javascript code is only selecting the RED divs and not both the RED divs and the WHITE divs.

Make the 4th line of code read:

```
$('.maine .resize_box').resizable({ handles:  'e' });
```

As an example, you can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/wnqj0uta/58/